# How to make a barchart with multiple datas using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm trying to do a barchart on python using matplotlib, but I do struggle even if I know that what I'm trying to do is very simple.

I have different variables of same lenght, imagine 4 lists :

```
run1 = [250,250,250,250]
run2 = [100,100,400,400]
run3 = [50,250,550,150]
run4 = [300,200,100,400]
```

And what I want is simply a graph with 4*4 bars. I want to group the first element of each list (here 250,100,50,300) and have four bars with different colors the height of which corresponding to the values on y axis. And then put a space, have again 4 bars with the next values (250,100,250,200) and so one.

How can I do that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the best way is to convert your data list to pandas DataFrame and plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

run1 = [250,250,250,250]
run2 = [100,100,400,400]
run3 = [50,250,550,150]
run4 = [300,200,100,400]

runs = pd.DataFrame({'Run 1': run1, 'Run 2': run2,
 'Run 3': run3, 'Run 4': run4})
runs.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it. First merge all the four lists together to make use of NumPy indexing to get one element from each list.

Here `alpha` parameter which controls the transparency of the bars is important to use because if you use opaque bars `alpha=1` then you will see only the highest bar because other bars will be hidden behind it. I used `alpha=0.2`. You can use any value you prefer.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

run1 = [250,250,250,250]
run2 = [100,100,400,400]
run3 = [50,250,550,150]
run4 = [300,200,100,400]

run_all = np.stack((run1, run2, run3, run4))

for i in range(len(run_all)):
    plt.bar(range(4), run_all[i, :], alpha=0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the thing is that when you do this you have a lot of different colors due to the transparency. I would prefer to have the bars alongside each others. So I can specify the color. Also, how to specify a label for each different bars ? For example run1, run2, run3 and four on the x axis ?